# Can common subexpression elimination be applied between functions?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction

I wonder if some parts of two similar functions are the same and the functions are executed sequentially with the same parameters,
or a function inside a loop has identical computations, will compiler do some optimizations like CSE (common subexpression elimination)
or loop-invariant code motion to reduce the redundancy?

Of course, if the function gets inlined, the compiler will find the chance to do the optimizations. But if the function isn't inlined, can compiler still find chances for eliminating the redundancy?

In other words, the compiler will try to find common subexpressions in a basic block or across basic blocks. How about function level?

Comment: It's possible, if the functions get inlined.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I mean the no-inline situation.

Comment: It's possible, if you invoke the santa is real clause.  Edit your question please.